# Getting the value from JSpinner (SWING)

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I need to get value from JSpinner.

```
private JSpinner[] timeSpinner;
private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Date time = new Date();
try {
  time = format.parse(timeSpinner[i].getValue().toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
data[i] = time.toString();
System.out.println(data[i]);
```

The error message:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 01 01:05:00 CET 1970"
```

Comment: Why this thread has been downvoted?

Comment: wondering about the downvote as well ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SimpleDateFormat you are creating has a different format from the date you are trying to parse:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Thu Jan 01 01:05:00 CET 1970
```

Have a look at the [SimpleDateFormat docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Edit: Actually looking again it looks like you already have a Date object why not just use that?

```
time = (Date)timeSpinner[i].getValue();
```

---

In order to turn the date you have into a String you just have to do the above to get a Date and then do

```
String formattedDate = format.format(time);
```

Comment: I need to format Thu Jan 01 01:05:00 CET 1970 into "HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 4):

I can't see there any reasons for casting and parsing, you have to read tutorial about [JSpinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and to set [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) for `JSpinner` instace, then you couldn't needed to solve parsing / casting `Date` instance from `JSpinner`

simple example

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TimeZoneSpinners {

    private final String[] zones = {"Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Hong_Kong",
        "Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/London",
        "America/New_York", "America/Los_Angeles"
    };
    private final JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[zones.length];
    private final SimpleDateFormat[] formats = new SimpleDateFormat[zones.length];
    private JSpinner spinner;
    private SpinnerDateModel model;
    private SimpleDateFormat format;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void makeUI() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        model.setValue(date);
        spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Date date = (Date) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    labels[i].setText(formats[i].format(date));
                }
            }
        });
        format = ((JSpinner.DateEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat();
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[0]));
        format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(zones.length, 2, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
            formats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formats[i].setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[i]));
            JLabel label = new JLabel(zones[i]);
            labels[i] = new JLabel(formats[i].format(date));
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(labels[i]);
        }
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        frame.add(spinner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimeZoneSpinners().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```