# Getting the value from a jSpinner

Tags: jspinner

I would not have throught this would be such a big problem, but im trying to get the value from a jSpinner called spinHours that is using the default SpinnerNumberModel.

```
spinHours.getValue().toString();
```

The above always returns 0. I need is as a string for later, but i've also tried:

```
SpinnerNumberModel model = (SpinnerNumberModel)spinHours.getModel();
int value = model.getNumber().intValue();
```

Where the value integer is 0 too.

Am i missing something really obvious?

When my jFrame loads i use the following line in the constructor to set the model for the jSpinner:

```
spinHours.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,99,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try

time = (Date)spinHours.getValue();
String formattedDate = format.format(time);

or 

jSp = spinHours.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,99,1));
Integer value = (Integer)jSp.getValue();
```

useful links:

[how can I get the value of a the selected item in a JSpinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380241/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-jspinner)

[Getting the value from JSpinner (SWING)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176698/getting-the-value-from-jspinner-swing)